# How do I make inputs part of a python script, so the input will forever be displayed every time the program is openned?

Tags: python, input

I'm trying to make a database-like program using python 3.8.2, and I'm trying to figure out how to make permanent changes to the script playing the role of a user. Is there a way to

A) Revieve an input from the user

B) Make that input a part of the script, so it will always show up when the program is opened

Comment: Your script should not edit itself. Save the information in a separate file that you re-read on startup.

Comment: So you are looking for [1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) and [2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) or [2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/interpreter.html#argument-passing) tells you how.

It would look something like:

```py
import sys
for script_argument in sys.argv:
  print(script_argument)
```

If you want something more complex, check out [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).